# convergence of series $ {n}^{p} \cdot \left\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis

$$ {n}^{p} \cdot \left\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right\}$$
determine the convergence of the series
$$ {n}^{p} \cdot \left\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right\} < {n}^{p} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{n}} < \frac{{n}^{p}}{n-1} < \frac{1}{{n}^{1-p}-{n}^{-p}} < \frac{1}{{n}^{1-p}} $$

so converges when p<0 how about other cases?

Comment: Are you sure of your current result? For instance, the second-to-last inequality seems wrong ($p$ should be $-p$, for a start), and why would $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{1-p}}$ converge for $1=p < 2$?

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you and it's been edited.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n-1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-n}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1})}=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}\right)}\approx \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$$

So use the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) between $n^p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ and $n^{p-3/2}$.

Comment: Do we always try to pack everything in the denominator when trying to compare with something using p-test?

Comment: AND how you see 5/2 is critical directly?

Comment: The usual trick is to change the difference of two "infinites" to the sum, by multiplying by the conjugate.  I didn't try to shove everything in the denominator, it just worked out that way.  What I *did* do was try to pull out the part that is going to infinity, and leave behind something that goes to a constant.

Comment: Just a comparison of what I did, why does using comparison at an early stage is not a good idea?

Comment: The comparison test is slightly easier to apply than the LCT, but much more frequently gives a useless result.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Using the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem%7D), we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt n}&=(n-1)^{-1/2}-n^{-1/2}\\\\
&=n^{-1/2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)-1\right)\\\\
&=\frac12n^{-3/2}+O\left(\frac1{n^{5/2}}\right)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}} - 1\right)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(  1+\frac{1}{2n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - 1\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)
\end{align}$$
using Taylor expansions: $(1+x)^\alpha = 1+\alpha x + o(x)$ for any fixed $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, when $x\to 0$.

Comment: Like mine. ;-))

Comment: Up to the name of the result used (Generalized Binomial Theorem / Taylor series expansion), quite, indeed :)

Comment: Great minds ... well, maybe yours is great, but mine ... not so much